# How to find all input elements with specific text on webpage with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

Basically what I am trying to do is find all of the input elements on a website containing a specific word and try to input text there. For example this website https://www.missyempire.com/customer/account/create/ has 2 input elements containing the key word "email". I know how to specify one but not find all, any help would be great.

Comment: Can you add your current code snippet? Minimum code showing what you are doing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all elements by using selenium `find_elements`. When you will provide locator to your `find_elements`, make that locator `parametrized` and pass your `input text` to that locator.

**For Example:**

```
text = 'email' -> This is your specific word
testEmails = ['123@example.com', '456@example.com'] -> These are your sample input values

PATH = r"your chromedriver exe path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.missyempire.com/customer/account/create/ ")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "firstname")))
allEmails = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//input[@name="{text}"]') -> This is your parametrized xpath locator which will receive your specific word
for email in allEmails:
    email.send_keys(random.choice(testEmails)) -> Select your input values random ally 
sleep(20)   -> This sleep is viewing the entered values before closing the browser
driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I used the part of your code and the output worked beautifully by sending the email to two sections instead of one containing the key word.

 Thank you so much for the quick response, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Trickster Kindly accept the answer if it solves your problem.